# mongoose find for same id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to get result for all array elements. But when this code runs, I get results only for `z[0]` and `z[1]` because `z[1]=z[2]`.
I need to find the same values. This is `console.log` result:

```
[ { _id: 5a621aa0232c231a74736b48,
    ad: 'sefer',
    soyad: 'eken',
    nick: 'Lonelman',
    email: 'seferftsukran@mynet.com',
    parola: '8790033749e6304a93bfd4af4aa49aa721bcfe29cfff15e38c5a41ce75687c94',
    resim: 'animals.jpg',
    __v: 0,
    arkadaslar: [],
    begeni: [],
    date: 2018-01-19T16:19:44.120Z },
  { _id: 5a621b0f232c231a74736b49,
    ad: 'şükran',
    soyad: 'eken',
    nick: 'Şükonella',
    email: 'seferftsukran@gmail.com',
    parola: '8790033749e6304a93bfd4af4aa49aa721bcfe29cfff15e38c5a41ce75687c94',
    resim: 'avatar-1514321231238.jpg',
    __v: 0,
    arkadaslar: [],
    begeni: [],
    date: 2018-01-19T16:21:35.117Z
} ]
```

---

```js
topics.findOne({topic:req.query.w},function(err,topic){
    comment.find({topicid:topic._id},function(err,comments){
    var z=[];
  for(var i=0;i<comments.length;i++){
 z.push(comments[i].userid)
} 
user.find({_id:z},function(err,userphoto){
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: Why should two different objects have the same id?!

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean find user in an Array of userId, you can use `$in`

```
topics.findOne({topic:req.query.w},function(err,topic){
    comment.find({topicid:topic._id},function(err,comments){
        var z=[];
        for(var i=0;i<comments.length;i++){
           z.push(comments[i].userid)
        }   
        user.find({_id: { $in:z} },function(err,userphoto){
       });
    });
})
```

Comment: i asked 3 questions-0 answer and - vote.i ask and answer so omg .

Answer (score 0):

I try this and work ty all.I edited my ejs file.Look at all please.

```js
<% for(var i = 0;i<comment.length;i++){%>

 
<span><%- comment[i].usernick%></span>
<%for(var a= 0;a<img2.length;a++){if(img2[a].nick==comment[i].usernick){%>
<img  style="width:30px" src="uploads/<%-img2[a].resim%>"></img>
<%}}%>

<% } %>
```